# Is there a way to make the grid bigger in the U.V. screen?

Tags: texturing

Is there a way to make the grid bigger in the U.V. screen? I know scaling the object in U.V scales the texture but what if I need two textures and they overlap? is there layer screens in U.V. editor? Sorry for asking a different question now.

Comment: Like is there a way to scale it up to make the texture show then make the the unwrap smaller to be able to organize it. Or am I going at this the wrong way haha?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: I'd say you are going about it the wrong way, it'd be better to do some reading on uv packing.

Answer (score 1):

You can have any number of UVs for a single mesh. In the object data tab of the Properties panel you'll find the UV Maps section. Select the verts of your model where you want texture1 to go and hit U-->Unwrap. That will create the first UV Map. Now hit the "+" button next to the window and select the verts where you want texture2 to go and hit U-->Unwrap. That will create UVMap.001. By control/clicking on the names you can change them (for example, "UVMap.001" to "Texture2" so it's easy to find later). You can do this many times but there is a limit (not sure what it is but high enough for most needs). Finally in the node editor Add-->Input-->UVMap, select map and plug into vector slot on your texture node. Repeat for all textures.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot! I'm big on organizing when it comes to technology. Saves a lot of time this way. Hierarchys are my best friend :D.